# Excel - Sum of values based on a drop down defining whether they are negative or positive

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I've tried searching for posts specifically on this, but am struggling to find what I'm looking for. I'm trying to do some fairly basic calculations based on a value in a drop down field for each row which determines whether the value is negative or positive.

In the example below, I would like to sum all the values in Column B based on a drop down value (Column C) which defines whether the value in column be should be added or subtracted from the total amount in C10.

I'll be honest, I have no idea how to even begin working out how to write the formula for the Credit/Debit values based on the drop down.

```
   A               B           C       D
1  DATE            VALUE       TYPE    DESCRIPTION
   ----            -----       ----    -----------
2  02/03/2015      £150        Debit   Currency Exchange
3  20/04/2015      £200        Debit   Currency Exchange
4  04/05/2015      £1000       Credit  Currency Exchange
5
6
7
8
9
10 TOTAL ADJUSTMENTS:          £650
```

I'm guessing I need to somehow use the SUMIF statement to define whether the type in Column C is Debit or Credit and then add/substract the corresponding value some how from the total amount?

Many thanks in advance for any assistance you may be able to offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

=SUMIF(C2:C9,"Credit",B2:B9)-SUMIF(C2:C9,"Debit",B2:B9)

The first Sumif sums up all the credits, the second Sumif sums up all the debits and the debit sum is then subtracted from the credit sum.

Comment: Hi Teylyn, that was exactly the solution. Thank you very much for for providing the formula, but more importantly for explaining to me how it works. This was really useful and I really appreciate you taking the time to help.